# What is the peak to peak voltage of a Colpitts Oscillator?

Tags: voltage, oscillator

I am designing a colpitts oscillator having a frequency of 100MHz. However, I am not sure how to calculate the peak to peak voltage for the sustained oscillations. Attached is my workings. Is the peak to peak voltage equal to the total voltage supplied minus the voltage drop across Rc? Thanks in advance for your help.[image]

Comment: Does that 19k collector resistor represent the load? An oscillator is meant to drive *something*, which is represented as a load resistor, and perhaps a reactive element as well. Adding a load will likely alter oscillator peak-to-peak voltage.

Comment: @glen_geek The oscillations are being passed to a Frequency Modulation circuit since the aim of this project is to design a FM circuit. Then again, what is the peak to peak voltage of the oscillations.

Comment: Why don't you let SPICE do the heavy lifting? Can't you put together a simulation of this circuit?

Comment: I don't think you can use the quiescent current (.3 mA) and voltage (4 V) to calculate the peak to peak voltage. Are the quoted numbers the quiescent values or something else? At most, they may form an upper bound on the peak to peak value (since current in Rc can't go below zero)

Comment: For oscillators the general rule is that they oscillate at the point (signal amplitude) where the **loopgain = 1**. Can you calculate the loopgain of the linearized circuit? Then add (an approximation of the) non-linearities of the amplifier to that. Then solve for loopgain = 1. It is not an easy thing to determine analytically.

Comment: The problem is that the oscillation will not be pure, it will have harmonics, and quite a few and substantial. The tricks you may see with diodes limiting the swing might tame them a bit, but only so much. This means that the whole stage is strongly non-linear, so a linear analysis will get you results that may be quite off from the actual result. I second the SPICE option.

Comment: @RyanPace Do you think that a transfer function of the linear part of the loop may be useful? (Don't forget to include the emitter's load on the base.) Did you develop one?